# How to rotate and move object in bevy

Tags: rust, bevy

I want to rotate my object by a given amount and translate it forward to create a steerable tank.

I couldn't find out how to do it, all the matrices, vectors, and quaternions make it difficult for me to find a solution.

This is the Unity equivalent of what i want to do:

```cs
transform.Rotate(0, 0, -turn_input * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
transform.position += transform.forward * drive * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

I used to use this code in Bevy 0.2.1 but it broke after updating to 0.4

```rust
*transform.value_mut() = *transform.value()
    * Mat4::from_rotation_translation(
        Quat::from_rotation_z(-turn_input * tank.turn_speed * time.delta_seconds),
        Vec3::unit_y() * drive * tank.speed * time.delta_seconds,
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to @Sleepyhead on discord.
It's close to the Unity code but 3 lines because you can't read and update on the same line.

Bevy only has `transform.forward()` (suggested by @Sleepyhead) which goes into the Z direction:
https://docs.rs/bevy/0.4.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Transform.html#method.forward

```rust
#[inline]
pub fn forward(&self) -> Vec3 {
    self.rotation * Vec3::unit_z()
}
```

I modified this code for the Y direction `transform.rotation * Vec3::unit_y()`
and use this in the final solution:

```rust
transform.rotate(Quat::from_rotation_z(-turn_input * tank.turn_speed * time.delta_seconds()));
let move_dir = transform.rotation * Vec3::unit_y() * drive * tank.speed * time.delta_seconds();
transform.translation += move_dir;
```

There is currently an open issue for adding more directions to Transform: https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/issues/1298

Answer (score 4):

That was [changed in Bevy 0.3](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-030-2020-11-03) with "Move transform data out of Mat4" ([PR #596](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/pull/596))

This changed, so instead of [`Transform`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.4.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Transform.html) having a `value: Mat4` field, then instead it would have [`translation: Vec3`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.4.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Transform.html#structfield.translation), [`rotation: Quat`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.4.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Transform.html#structfield.rotation), and [`scale: Vec3`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.4.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Transform.html#structfield.scale).

If you want a literal translation of your code, then that would be:

```rust
transform = Transform::from_matrix(
    transform.compute_matrix()
        * Mat4::from_rotation_translation(
            Quat::from_rotation_z(-turn_input * tank.turn_speed * time.delta_seconds),
            Vec3::unit_y() * drive * tank.speed * time.delta_seconds,
        ),
);
```

However, it might be more straightforward to use [`transform.rotate()`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.4.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Transform.html#method.rotate) and/or assign directly to [`transform.translation`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.4.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Transform.html#structfield.translation) and [`transform.rotation`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.4.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Transform.html#structfield.rotation).